# Converting text files to docx via dotx

Tags: python, docx

Given thousands of text files, how do you convert text files (.txt) to Word files (.docx) using a template (.dotx)? Is there any command line for Windows to perform the task? Python code should work as well.

Here is a sample text:

```
First line
السطر الثاني
Third line
```

I want this text rendered in Word as:

[image: snapshot from word]

using the following template:

https://file.io/O6HraiFeWeO3

[docx, and dotx files]

Using the following Python code works only partially. It renders entire text including Arabic to Calibri. Whereas, I want it to assign Calibri to Latin/English text, and Arabic Typesetting to Complex/Arabic scripts:

```
import docx

text_file     = 'input.txt'
template_file = 'templateDOC.docx'
output_file   = 'output.docx'

with open(text_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    text = f.read()

doc = docx.Document(template_file)
doc.add_paragraph(text)
doc.save(output_file)
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310786/how-to-convert-txt-file-or-pdf-to-word-doc-using-python

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not a template based solution. I need text to be structed in a specific way as set in the template.

Comment: What structure does this template do ?

Comment: It sets "Calibri" font for Latin text; and "Arabic Typesetting" font for Complex scripts.

Comment: Maybe a couple of sample files would help...

Comment: Sure! Consider the following lines:

Hello world!
مرحبا بالعالم
Goodbye World!
وادعا أيتها الدنيا!
The end

I want this to be formatted such that English sentences be set to "Calibri" fonts, and Arabic sentences to a font named "Arabic Typesetting".

Comment: PowerShell works better with MS Office functions than Python, but Word also has a really, really good macro system that would probably be a very good place to build this sort or solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) for this task with a command like this:

```
pandoc input.txt --reference-doc template.docx -o output.docx
```

From what I see, it converts the fonts correctly. The output is in one line though, unless you enter two line breaks, so you may need to modify your template for that.

And for lots of files:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt -Recurse | % { pandoc $_.FullName --reference-doc template.docx -o "$($_.FullName)_output.docx" }
```

Comment: Quick question: is it possible to have pandog run a macro in the template? Currently, it doesn't apply designated fonts to Arabic script. Maybe with running a macro it could accomplish this task.

Comment: WDYM? I tested the specified input and it got changed to `Arabic Typesetting`. What happens in your case?

Comment: It produces a one liner "First line السطر الثاني Third line" with just one font Calibri.

Comment: That's weird. What are you opening it with and on which system? I assume you used latest Pandoc? As for macros, no, it doesn't support them currently AFAIK, just template styles.

Comment: Yes, I used the most recent pandog on Windows 10, and 11.